# How to open a tabpage and change the tabpage text base on the row selected in the datagridview?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a datagridview with datasource, and I'm planning on opening a tab page when the user doubleclicks on the selected row.

This is my `CellDoubleClick Event`

```
private void dataGridCust_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow row = (dataGridCust.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
        plate = row["Plate No."].ToString();
        custRecord();
        string tabName = "Job " + plate;
        tabJob.Text = tabName;
        tabView.Controls.Add(tabJob); 
    }
```

It opens my `tabJob` page,

[tabJob opened as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ0Om.jpg)

As you can see it did change the tabpage text, but when I try to select another row or the same row. The tabpage will be

[Not the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKsKb.jpg)

Now both tab pages are set with the same `Text`, and a blank page and having a problem with

[Tab index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqwYx.jpg)

I have designed the `tabJob` base on the first picture (still on a scratch, but will place some `Label`, `Combobox`, `Buttons`, `DataGridView`).

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you're refering `tabJob` to the previously created one. So the tab 'Job AAC-2266' first changed its name into 'AAI-4787', and then a duplicate was created.

Comment: Yes, that is also what I'm thinking. But I don't know how to open a tabpage and change its text so that it will be unique.

Comment: Sorry, I was absent. You can make a new tabpage `tabView.Controls.Add(new TabPage(tabName) { Name = tabName })` and later get that tab by: `Controls.Find(*Name of the tab*, true)[0]`

Comment: It opens a new tabpage with the correct name. But how can I call tabJob where my controls are there?

Comment: For example when you need to call the 'Job AAC-2266' tab, assign `tabJob = (TabPage)Controls.Find("Job AAC-2266", true)[0];` and use it afterwards.

Comment: `tabView.Controls.Add(new TabPage(tabName) { Name = tabName }); tabJob = (TabPage)Controls.Find(tabName, true)[0];` I have added your code after `string tabName = "Job " + plate;` Still it shows a blank tabpage.

Comment: It is my understanding that the newly created tabpage doesn't have controls such as customer details groupbox. In that case, a new tabpage doesn't contain any controls by default so you will have to add controls by yourself.

Comment: I see, but what I want is that it will open my created `Tabpage`(`tabJob`) but only with different `Tabname`.

Comment: I would use an if-else to check if a tab already exists before creating one. `if (tabView.Controls.ContainsKey(tabName)) .....`